# No matching factory method found: factory bean 'freeMarkerConfigurationFactory'; factory method 'createConfiguration()'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to use SpringMVC and freemarker in my project. But i'm getting below error when i try to create Configuration object using ApplicationContext.getBean(String) method:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'freeMarkerConfiguration' defined in class path resource [META-INF/applicationContext.xml]: No matching factory method found: factory bean 'freeMarkerConfigurationFactory'; factory method 'createConfiguration()'. Check that a method with the specified name and arguments exists and that it is non-static.

My applicationContext.xml is defined as:

```
<bean id="freeMarkerConfigurationFactory"
class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
    <property name="templateLoaderPath" value="classpath:/" />
    <property name="preferFileSystemAccess" value="false" />
</bean>
<bean id="freeMarkerConfiguration" class="freemarker.template.Configuration"
factory-bean="freeMarkerConfigurationFactory" factory-method="createConfiguration"
scope="prototype" />
```

pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.13.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
    <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.25-incubating</version>
</dependency>
```

And i'm using JBoss EAP 6.4.x as application server.